# How to make a server side youtube player so the time played would be same for all users?

Tags: html, node.js, iframe, youtube

Take a look at plug.dj website, if you refresh a currently playing song, the timing won't be affected on the server and will not affect it.

I prefer node.js but any other language is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, what you are after is a shared youtube experience. I would do the following...

When a client joins, the server sends to the client a "start time", which indicates where the client should start watching the Youtube video and in such way "join" the rest of the viewers. Server needs to keep track of this time from the moment viewers start watching. The client should periodically make sure that the video is in sync with the time of others by having a timer outside of the youtube video, in browser. Youtube video can become out-of-sync due to buffering, a simple timer/clock in browser cannot.